# trace register value in llvm

Tags: llvm

In llvm, can one trace back to the instruction that defines the value for a particular register? For example, if I have an instruction as:

```
  %add14 = add i32 %add7, %add5
```

Is here a way for me to trace back to the instruction where add5 is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are no registers in LLVM IR: all those things with `%` in their names are just names of values. You don't store information inside those things, they are not variables or memory locations, they are just names. I recommend reading about [SSA form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form), which helps explains this further.

In any case, what you need to do is invoke the `getOperand(n)` method on the instruction to get its nth operand - for example, `getOperand(0)` in your example will return the value named `%add7`. You can then check whether that value is indeed an instruction (as opposed to, say, a function argument) by checking its type (`isa<Instruction>`).

To emphasize - calling the `getOperand` method *will* give you the actual place in which the operand is defined, nothing else is required.